# Variance of normal cdf?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $Z \sim N(0,1)$, how to calculate $Var(\Phi(\frac{a - bZ}{c}))$ with $a,b,c >0$?

I know how to solve $E[\Phi(\frac{a - bZ}{c})]$, but how to find $E[\Phi^2(\frac{a- bZ}{c})]$? Thanks!

Here is my attempt to solve $E[\Phi(\frac{a-bZ}{c})]$:

$E[\Phi(\frac{a-bZ}{c})] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(X \le \frac{a-bz}{c})\phi(z)dz \\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X \le \frac{a- bZ}{c}| Z = z) \phi(z)dz \\
= P(X \le \frac{a-bZ}{c}) \\
= P(bZ + cX \le a) \\
= P(N(0,c^2+b^2) \le a) \\
= \Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{c^2 + b^2}})$

Comment: Do you mean $Var(\frac{a-bZ}{c})$? $\Phi(\frac{a-bZ}c)$ is just a number, not a random variable.

Comment: @johndoe it's a function of the rv $Z$ and thus an RV.

Comment: @wolfies I updated it

Comment: See:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142931/